# UIButton is only responsive sometimes when pressing down

Tags: swift, uibutton, uikit

I've been working on an app and have never had an issue like this before. I also didn't have this issue for most of my development time until the very end. I'm starting to think it is because of something I added to the view controller that is making the button only responsive sometimes. Here is my entire ViewController and the method that isn't firing every time is at the bottom.

```
class StartViewController: UIViewController {

var timer: Timer?
var timer2: Timer?

let header: UILabel = {
    let label = UILabel()
    label.text = ""
    label.font = UIFont.customBoldFont(size: 40)
    label.textColor = UIColor.textColor()
    return label
}()

let cursor: UIView = {
    let view = UIView()
    view.backgroundColor = UIColor.textColor()
    return view
}()

let startButton: UIButton = {
    let button = UIButton()
    button.setTitle("Start", for: .normal)
    button.setTitleColor(.white, for: .normal)
    button.backgroundColor = UIColor.appColor()
    button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(start), for: .touchUpInside)
    button.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
    button.isEnabled = true
    button.isMultipleTouchEnabled = true
    return button
}()

let epmLabel: UILabel = {
    let label = UILabel()
    label.text = "EPM"
    label.font = UIFont.customBoldFont(size: 25)
    label.textColor = UIColor.textColor()
    return label
}()

let epmValue: UILabel = {
    let label = UILabel()
    label.text = ""
    label.font = UIFont.customFont(size: 20)
    label.textColor = UIColor.textColor()
    return label
}()

let accuracyLabel: UILabel = {
    let label = UILabel()
    label.text = "Accuracy"
    label.font = UIFont.customBoldFont(size: 25)
    label.textColor = UIColor.textColor()
    return label
}()

let accuracyValue: UILabel = {
    let label = UILabel()
    label.text = ""
    label.font = UIFont.customFont(size: 20)
    label.textColor = UIColor.textColor()
    return label
}()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    create()
    getStats()
    animateHeader()
}

func create() {
    view.backgroundColor = UIColor.backgroundColor()
    view.isUserInteractionEnabled = true

    let titleView = UIView()
    view.addSubview(titleView)
    titleView.anchor(top: view.topAnchor, left: view.leftAnchor, bottom: view.centerYAnchor, right: view.rightAnchor, paddingTop: 0, paddingLeft: 0, paddingBottom: 0, paddingRight: 0, width: 0, height: 0)

    view.addSubview(header)
    header.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    header.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: titleView.centerYAnchor).isActive = true
    header.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
    header.addSubview(cursor)
    cursor.anchor(top: header.topAnchor, left: nil, bottom: header.bottomAnchor, right: header.rightAnchor, paddingTop: 3, paddingLeft: 0, paddingBottom: -3, paddingRight: -7, width: 2, height: 0)
    cursor.layer.cornerRadius = 1

    view.addSubview(startButton)
    startButton.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    startButton.constrainSize(width: 300, height: 60)
    startButton.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
    startButton.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerYAnchor).isActive = true
    startButton.layer.cornerRadius = 30

    let statsView = UIView()
    view.addSubview(statsView)
    statsView.anchor(top: view.centerYAnchor, left: view.leftAnchor, bottom: view.bottomAnchor, right: view.rightAnchor, paddingTop: 0, paddingLeft: 0, paddingBottom: 0, paddingRight: 0, width: 0, height: 0)

    let epmStack = UIStackView(arrangedSubviews: [epmLabel, epmValue])
    epmStack.axis = .vertical
    epmStack.alignment = .center
    epmStack.spacing = 5
    view.addSubview(epmStack)
    epmStack.anchor(top: nil, left: startButton.leftAnchor, bottom: nil, right: startButton.centerXAnchor, paddingTop: 0, paddingLeft: 0, paddingBottom: 0, paddingRight: 0, width: 0, height: 0)
    epmStack.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: statsView.centerYAnchor).isActive = true

    let accuracyStack = UIStackView(arrangedSubviews: [accuracyLabel, accuracyValue])
    accuracyStack.axis = .vertical
    accuracyStack.alignment = .center
    accuracyStack.spacing = 5
    view.addSubview(accuracyStack)
    accuracyStack.anchor(top: nil, left: startButton.centerXAnchor, bottom: nil, right: startButton.rightAnchor, paddingTop: 30, paddingLeft: 0, paddingBottom: 0, paddingRight: 0, width: 0, height: 0)
    accuracyStack.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: statsView.centerYAnchor).isActive = true
}

func getStats() {
    let defaults = UserDefaults.standard
    let epm = defaults.integer(forKey: "epm")
    let accuracy = defaults.double(forKey: "accuracy")
    //Check if first load
    if(accuracy == -1.0 && epm == -1) {
        epmValue.text = "0"
        accuracyValue.text = "0%"
    } else {
        epmValue.text = String(describing: epm)
        accuracyValue.text = String(describing: accuracy) + "%"
    }
    if(accuracy >= 70.0) { accuracyValue.textColor = UIColor.rgb(red: 34, green: 181, blue: 98) }
    if(accuracy < 70.0 && accuracy > 30.0) { accuracyValue.textColor = UIColor.rgb(red: 255, green: 241, blue: 117) }
    if(accuracy <= 30.0) { accuracyValue.textColor = UIColor.rgb(red: 242, green: 107, blue: 90) }
}

func animateHeader() {
    let str = ["E","m","o","j","i"," ","T","y","p","e", " "]
    var i = 0
    timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 0.2, repeats: true) { (timer) in
        if(i == str.count - 1) {
            self.cursor.alpha = 0
            self.header.text?.append(str[i])
            i+=1
        }
        if(i >= str.count) {
            self.timer?.invalidate()
            self.animateEmojis()
        } else {
            self.header.text?.append(str[i])
            i+=1
        }
    }
}

func animateEmojis() {
    var emojiOptions = ["","","","","","","☀️","⚽️","","","","","","","","","","","","",""]
    emojiOptions.shuffle()
    var i = 0
    var counter = 0
    timer2 = Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 1.25, repeats: true) { (timer) in
        if(i >= emojiOptions.count) { i = 0 }
        if(counter >= 100) {
            self.timer2?.invalidate()
        } else {
            self.header.text?.removeLast()
            self.header.text?.append(emojiOptions[i])
        }
        i+=1
        counter+=1
    }
}

override func viewWillTransition(to size: CGSize, with coordinator: UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator) {
    self.view.setNeedsUpdateConstraints()
}

@objc func start() {
    print("Activated")
    timer?.invalidate()
    timer2?.invalidate()
    let mainVC = UINavigationController(rootViewController: MainViewController())
    self.present(mainVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
}
```

I have a print statement that checks to see when the button was clicked and it is only printed when the event happens (not every time I try to click on it). I cannot figure out for the life of me why this is happening now.

Comment: Are we talking about `startButton`? I would expect it to _never_ work. You cannot say `addTarget(self)` in the initializer of a view controller property.

Comment: doing it this way has worked for me throughout my iOS development career. I don't know how that would be an issue.

Comment: Change `let startButton` to `lazy var startButton` and it should begin to work.

Comment: Seems to be working now. Thanks. Just out of curiosity, how come doing it previously worked every once in a while?